# What exactly is LDI (Landing Direction Indicator), what does it look like, where should it be, how does it work and how do pilots use it?

Tags: general-aviation, airport, aeronautical-information

What exactly is LDI (Landing Direction Indicator), what does it look like, where should it be, how does it work and how do pilots use it?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I need a more explanatory and detailed answer. I have learned that they have different structures in Europe and America without knowing what they do and what they are used for.

Comment: This may answer all your questions: [What is this radar-like thing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39216/3201). This is the model used in Turkey, it's not always wind-rotated, it can be manual.

Comment: The answer to this question was more appropriate, thank you.